# When does the catch arguments get checked in a try/catch block c#

Tags: c#, try-catch

I'm having an issue with a try/catch block, but I can't seem to find out exactly how try/catch works when it's running that I think might have my answer.  I have the following try/catch block:

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (MyException e)
{
    Log.Error("oh no!");
    throw;
}
```

Now when I run this code I'm getting a `System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type SDK.MyException from assembly "SDKSampleLibrary, Version... etc` error.

I'm wondering 2 things.  First, when does the computer check to see if MyException is there.  Is it when it gets to the `try` or when it gets to the `catch`?  Second, the SDKSampleLibrary.dll is there.  How do I tell why it's not seeing it?

Comment: The details are in the `...etc...` part

Comment: I'm willing to bet there is a version conflict with some DLL, probably that SDKSampleLibrary, and that the wrong version is being used at run-time. Check the exact file that's referenced in your solution, and add a tiny bit of code somewhere in your program to display the location and version of the DLL used at run-time. They should match.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  It looks like the setup for these tests was copying the wrong .dll.    Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If the class MyException gets thrown within the try area, it will get handled inside the catch,  See my example below where i throw a new exception which would get handled by the catch statement. However any other kinds of exceptions would not be handled/

```
try
{
    throw(new MyException()); // handled by the catch
    throw(new ParseException()); //not handled.
    int test = "test" //not handled
}
catch (MyException e)
{
    Log.Error("oh no!");
    throw;
}
```

can also catch general exceptions to catch ALL exceptions like:

```
try
{
    throw(new MyException()); // handled by the catch
    throw(new ParseException()); //handled.
    int test = "test" //handled
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.Error("oh no!");
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler sees the class since it is blue and does not give compile errors. The problems is happening when you are running the code. I think the problem is in de code that throws the exception which cannot create it. You could try to use the normal Exception type in the catch block and then set a break point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the try/catch block but rather the problem is the type of exception that you are trying to catch as specified by the exception that your code is throwing. This exception occurs when the runtime tries to load the **MyException** object. You should make sure that the **MyException** inherits either from the **Exception** base class or from any of its children.